# How to make IsAjaxRequest perform consistently with IE?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When using IE IsAjaxRequest for the following code can return both true and false with the same `ajaxUrl`

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
});
```

Following lines were added in pursuit to resolve the issue:

```
headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
cache: false,
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've edited